# Tell chef-client to use installed ruby path instead of omnibus ruby path?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Writing a recipe that installs a version of ruby system wide, installs dashing and deploys dashing on thin. To install ruby, I am using the following community cookbook https://github.com/fnichol/chef-ruby_build in my recipe, which installs ruby and the required gems at the path provided which is /usr/local/project_name/ruby. (Note : This does not add the installed ruby path to the PATH variable) When I run the chef-client, it always tries to look at the omnibus ruby path(/opt/chef/embedded/ruby) and tries to locate the gems available under it, hence it fails to run dashing, which has calls to bundle and thin , within its source. Following is the recipe , and I run it using chef-cluster 10.24v on skyboxlabs. Is there a way to specify the installed ruby path to use while running chef-client ?

```
# Cookbook Name:: program_dashboard
# Recipe:: default
include_recipe "ruby_build"

branch_name = node['program-dashboard']['branch_or_tag']
ruby_version = node['ruby']['version']
repo_url = node['dashboard_repo']
ruby_prefix_path = node['ruby']['prefix_path']
dashboard_repo_path = node['dashboard_repo_path']
ruby_home = ::File.expand_path('bin',ruby_prefix_path)
dashing = ::File.expand_path('dashing', ruby_home)
bundle_install = "#{::File.expand_path('bundle', ruby_home)} install"

package 'git' do
  action :install
  not_if "which git"
end

ruby_build_ruby ruby_version do
  user "root"
  prefix_path ruby_prefix_path
  definition ruby_version
  action :install
end

#Getting the latest from  repository
log "Getting the latest from the program-dev-dashboard repo"
  git dashboard_repo_path do
  repository repo_url
  reference branch_name
  user "root"
end

%w{bundler dashing}.each do |pkg|
  gem_package pkg do
    gem_binary "#{ruby_home}/gem"
  end
end

execute bundle_install do
  cwd dashboard_repo_path
  not_if "bundle check --gemfile #{::File.expand_path('Gemfile',dashboard_repo_path)}"
end

#Cycle the webserver
log "Getting the Dashboard Up and Running"
bash "cycle server" do
  user "root"
  cwd dashboard_repo_path
  flags "-e"
  code <<-EOH
  echo "Stopping the dashing server"
  #{dashing} stop  //fails here [1]
  echo "Starting the dashing server"
  #{dashing} start -d
  EOH
end
```

[1] since dashing calls bundle exec thin commands which it does not find in the omnibus ruby, how can I make chef-client to look for gems in the installed ruby path.

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Formatted. Here is the gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8960568

Comment: Did not want to modify the PATH variable on the production boxes to include the custom ruby install path, hence used a hack and called the bundle exec thin start/stop to start/stop dashing server. Here is the gist of the new code. https://gist.github.com/sompa/9008544